# Silverlight Doesn't Call OnLoad Parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, silverlight

I've set up my Silverlight ASPX page like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ASPResources/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="SilverlightPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Adapt.Presentation.AssetInventory.SilverlightPage"
Title="Xivic" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/ASPResources/MasterPage.master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Silverlight" Namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls"
TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" id="silverlightport">
    var silverlightControl = null;
    function pluginLoaded(sender, args)
    {
        silverlightControl = sender.getHost();
    }

    function externalCommand(data)
    {
        if (silverlightControl != null)
        {
            silverlightControl.Content.JSR.ExternalCommand(data);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Couldn't get silverlight host object in SilverlightPage.aspx");
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:Silverlight ID="SilverlightLaunchPage" EnableGPUAcceleration="true" runat="server"
    Source="~/ClientBin/Xivic.xap" Width="100%" Height="100%" InitParameters="onLoad=pluginLoaded" />
```

Silverlight starts up and the *pluginLoaded* function must not be being called because when I call the *externalCommand* function the *silverlightControl* variable isn't set. So either my Silverlight page hasn't loaded, which I'm quite sure it has or my onLoad event must not be hooked in properly which is more likely because I have little-to-none ASP knowledge.

Could someone please fill me in on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Show how you make the call to externalCommand

Comment: The call to externalCommand is not the problem. When I comment out the if statement and just put an alert, the alert fires.

The problem is that I can't get the Silverlight control host because it's not getting assigned because the function isn't getting hit.

Comment: are you calling onload as well? because something doesn't look right with `InitParameters="onLoad=pluginLoaded"`

Comment: Show app startup in SL control

Comment: I'm not calling onLoad, Silverlight is supposed to call that when it loads but it doesn't. The parameters in the InitParameters property are supposed to work the same way as **<param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded"/>**.

Comment: I don't believe so. checking now

Comment: `private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("JSR", new JavaScriptReceiver());
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Silverlight 5 control. I adapted it to what you have in your example

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..\Scripts\Silverlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function onSilverlightError(sender, args) {
            var appSource = "";
            if (sender != null && sender != 0) {
                appSource = sender.getHost().Source;
            }

            var errorType = args.ErrorType;
            var iErrorCode = args.ErrorCode;

            if (errorType == "ImageError" || errorType == "MediaError") {
                return;
            }

            var errMsg = "Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + appSource + "\n";

            errMsg += "Code: " + iErrorCode + "    \n";
            errMsg += "Category: " + errorType + "       \n";
            errMsg += "Message: " + args.ErrorMessage + "     \n";

            if (errorType == "ParserError") {
                errMsg += "File: " + args.xamlFile + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
            }
            else if (errorType == "RuntimeError") {
                if (args.lineNumber != 0) {
                    errMsg += "Line: " + args.lineNumber + "     \n";
                    errMsg += "Position: " + args.charPosition + "     \n";
                }
                errMsg += "MethodName: " + args.methodName + "     \n";
            }

            throw new Error(errMsg);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="silverlightport">
        var silverlightControl = null;
        function pluginLoaded(sender, args)
        {
            silverlightControl = sender.getHost();
        }

        function externalCommand(data)
        {
            if (silverlightControl != null)
            {
                silverlightControl.Content.JSR.ExternalCommand(data);
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Couldn't get silverlight host object in SilverlightPage.aspx");
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height: 100%">
        <div id="silverlightControlHost">
            <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
                <param name="source" value="../ClientBin/Xivic.xap" />
                <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                <param name="onLoad" value="pluginLoaded" />
                <param name="background" value="#F2F2F2" />
                <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
                <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration: none">
                    <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style: none" />
                </a>
            </object>
            <iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility: hidden; height: 0; width: 0; border: 0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The paths may need to change to match your file structures

Comment: The _OnClientPluginLoaded_ fix doesn't work for me, the silverlightControl remains unset and Visual Studio tells me that **"Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'OnClientPluginLoaded' is not a valid attribute of element 'Silverlight'"** and I'm unsure of where to put the object tag for the second fix.

Comment: The version you are using is very old. I'll show you How I currently set it up for Silvelright5

Comment: I tried your version of the ASPX file but for some reason my whole application is broken. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the newer <param/> tag?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. I'll take a look around the webs but this is how I've been using it since I first started coding silverlight applications.